# How to cache Rails API actions

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-api, actioncontroller

**What is the best and correct approach to do caching for actions?**

- Am I forced to `ActionController::Base`?
- Is there another way (keeping ActionController::API present)?
- Do I have to push caching down to Model layer?

I saw that Rails 6 (maybe prior) does not support action caching out of the box anymore. The caching was extracted to a gem: `actionpack-action_caching` https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching. I installed it, but it seems not working with `ActionController::API`, it only works with `ActionController::Base`.

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API`

must be changed to

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Then, and only then I can cache an action like so:

```rb
    class CategoryController < ApplicationController
      caches_action :index
      def index
        @root_categories = Category.roots
      end
    end
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The gem adds these methods to your controllers by including ActionController::Caching in ActionController::Base ([see here](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching/blob/7bdfa663274a2620dde8daad7dcb995c1cfef840/lib/action_controller/action_caching.rb#L15)). To add this behaviour to controllers that don't extend from ActionController::Base, simply include ActionController::Caching.

e.g.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Caching
end
```